# Debian: cannot create rfcomm0

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

On Debian Jessie 8.2:
I'm trying to create the following device: /dev/rfcomm0 in order to connect my arduino via bluetooth module HC-05, but no success.
Here are the steps I'm following:

1) I guess my HC-05 called FOO is recognised and properly configured, because

```
hcitool scan
```

reports

```
98:D3:31:xx:xx:xx   FOO
```

xx are just a mask I use here for privacy.

2) I added the file /etc/bluetooth/rfcomm.conf

```
rfcomm0 {
# Automatically bind the device at startup
bind yes;
# Bluetooth address of the device
device 98:D3:31:xx:xx:xx;
# RFCOMM channel for the connection
channel 1;
# Description of the connection
comment "FOO";
}
```

3) I restarted bluetooth service

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart
```

response is:

```
[ ok ] Restarting bluetooth (via systemctl): bluetooth.service.
```

Nevertheless device rfcomm0 is not created. 
I'm following the instructions here:

[Bluetooth serial communication with HC-05](https://myraspberryandme.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/bluetooth-serial-communication-with-hc-05/)

I did this operation months ago on another Linux system (it was ubuntu) and I can remember
evertything went well: the port was created. Probably I'm missing some important step!
Thanks a lot, 
Valerio

UPDATE:

this command

```
sdptool records 98:D3:31:xx:xx:xx
```

reports

```
Service Name: Dev B
Service RecHandle: 0x10000
Service Class ID List:
"Serial Port" (0x1101)
Protocol Descriptor List:
"L2CAP" (0x0100)
"RFCOMM" (0x0003)
Channel: 1
Language Base Attr List:
code_ISO639: 0x656e
encoding:    0x6a
base_offset: 0x100
```

I think this confirms that the channel in rfcomm.conf is 1

Comment: Does manually binding work? That is, from the command line: `sudo rfcomm bind 0 98:D3:31:xx:xx:xx 1`

Comment: Ye it works, rfcomm0 is created. Nevertheless the port is busy. I'm testing it with a Processing sketch which lists the available ports and then try to open the selected port.  In this test I can see that Processing tries to open the port "/dev/rfcomm0" but fails, and the response is "Error opening serial port /dev/rfcomm0: Port busy"

Comment: UPDATE: maybe it is solved! if I run Processing as sudoer the port result ok! I'll do right now some communication test in order to check the communication is ok!

Answer (score 2):

Ok , thanks to Kaylum this is solved!

The manual binding create the device rfcomm0

```
sudo rfcomm bind 0 98:D3:31:xx:xx:xx 1
```

Then, in order to make Processing write/read on the created port,
I needed to run Processing as sudoer, otherwise Processing says that the port exists but is busy. As sudoer, I can confirm that the port correctly sends data back and forth between Arduino and Processing!